# Entity Framework entity state is modified without any modification

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following issue on update of the entities. Given below is my WCF method. (Update is called by public Save method after determining if it is update or add)

```
protected bool UpdateSalesMaster(SalesMaster order)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        SalesMaster original = context.SalesMasters.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderID == order.OrderID);

        if (original != null)
        {
            context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(order);

            foreach (SalesDetail detail in order.SalesDetails)
            {
                if (detail.OrderDetailID == 0)
                    context.SalesDetails.Add(detail);
                else
                {
                    SalesDetails originalDetail = context.SalesDetails.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderDetailID == detail.OrderDetailID);
                    if (originalDetail != null)
                        context.Entry(originalDetail).CurrentValues.SetValues(detail);
                }
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FaultException(string.Format("Invalid Order specified: {0}", order.OrderID));
        }
    }
}
```

When I just update the OrderDate in SalesMaster and don't change any in the detail, an update query is fired to the database for detail. I expected to see Update query only for SalesMaster.

Can someone let me know what am I doing wrong here? I don't want to fire update queries to the DB if nothing is changed.

I use the approach of getting the original value from the database to determine if any values are updated using context.Entry(originalDetail).CurrentValues.SetValues(detail);

I also override the SaveChanges to set the LastModified date by checking for IAuditable implementation of the entity. This is when I find that the state of the detail entity is identified as modified. But the only update that happens in the DB is LastModifiedBy which was updated in my save changes. I am not sure how it was set to state of Modified when nothing changed in detail.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>();

    if (changeSet != null)
    {
        foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(c => c.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                entry.Entity.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;

            if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                entry.Property(a => a.CreatedByUser).IsModified = false;
                entry.Property(a => a.DateCreated).IsModified = false;
            }
            entry.Entity.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
    try
    {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

My solution structure is:

1. Client - Windows forms UI
2. Entities - POCO as seperate library
3. WCF - All business logic, add, update, delete of objects.
4. Data - Entity Framework context with Fluent mapping.

Comment: Does IAuditable contain the Modified State of the detached objects?  Have you checked the state on these objects? AFAIK there is no cascading updates, everything needs to be done explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you set up you POCOs, EF will default to one of two ways to check changes on an entity.

If ALL your POCOs properties are virtual, EF will use proxy object that inherit your POCO type, with all the properties overridden to track changes.

I assume that in this circumstance, using SetValues on the whole object WILL trigger the dirty flag, that will cause EF to generate an Update query to the database.

If your are not using proxies, your IAuditable implementation would be the primary suspect as brumScouse suggested.